# Linear $S^{2k}$-bundles over $S^{4k}$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, fibre-bundles, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

By the [classification of Dold and Whitney](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970030), linear $S^2$-bundles over $S^4$ are classified by their first Pontryagin class $p_1$, which takes the value $4\lambda$ for the bundle corresponding to $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}\cong\pi_3(\mathrm{SO}(3))$.

> Is there an analogous classification for linear $S^{2k}$-bundles over $S^{4k}$ in terms of $p_k$?

As a first step one could try to determine the group $\pi_{4k-1}(\mathrm{SO}(2k+1))$. By using the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for the fibration $\mathrm{SO}(m)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{SO}(m+1)\to S^m$ and by using Serre's result that there are finite groups $F_k$, so that
$$\pi_{m+n}(S^m)\cong\begin{cases} \mathbb{Z},\quad & n=0,\\\mathbb{Z}\oplus F_k,\quad &m=2k,n=2k-1,\\0,\quad &\text{else},\end{cases}$$
an inductive argument shows that $\pi_{4k-1}(\mathrm{SO}(2k+1))\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus F_k^\prime$ for $F^\prime_k$ finite. Is it known what the value of $p_k$ is for a primitive element of infinite order in $\pi_{4k-1}(\mathrm{SO}(2k+1))$?

Comment: Off the top of my head I know that $F'_k$ is 2-torsion (since $\pi_{4k-1}SO_{2k+1}\cong\pi_{4k-1}SO_{2k+1}\cong_{(\frac{1}{2})}\pi_{4k-1}Sp_k$, and this latter group is easily seen to be $\mathbb{Z}$). Inspection seems to indicate that $F'_k$ is generally nontrivial.

Comment: It comes down to computing the Hurewicz map for $BSO(2k+1)$, right?